# Spreadsheet how to get rows of filled cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to know if there is a way to do the following in a spreadsheet (Excel, Calc, etc.).

If I start from the following spreadsheet:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I 
-------------------------------- 
1 |       X     X  X
2 |    X        X     X     X
3 | X                               
--------------------------------
```

I would like to be able to get the columns that contain some value in the range that I have passed. For example:

```
Function(A1:I1) = {C,E,F}
Function(A1:I1) = {B,E,G,I}
Function(A1:I1) = {A}
```

Can you think of any ideas to get what I need? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which application are you using, you have tagged multiple spreadsheet applications, which may all have different solutions to your answer

Comment: `FILTER()` is a good starting point. Furthermore, I don't see any difference in the functions you added as sample.

Comment: Can you give us a bit of context plz? - usually when people ask for a list of column letters or row numbers this is just a step on the way to another goal which is not revealed to us.

Comment: @A.Steer I'm using Google Spreeadsheets, but if you don't have any solution for that, you can share your solution for Microsoft Excel or Libreoffice Calc ;)

Comment: @TomSharpe Each row is for a worker. Each worker select a taks (the column). So I wanted to build a table with the choices of every worker.

Comment: For example, for LibreOffice Calc, a array formula like `{="{" & TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(B2:J2="X";$B$1:$J$1;""))  & "}"}` will give the result that you have shown. But @TomSharpe is right - you must have meant something else. Therefore, give more information about the task.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:J10="",,B1:J1&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]